# html5 and javascript: is setTimeout breaking this?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I am confused as to why the following html is not working.
I would expect it to keep sending alerts but it stops after one.
Furthermore, the "left fn" alert never occurs!
Can anyone explain this to me?
I am using html5 with javascript in firefox on ubuntu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <script>
      function alertme() {
      alert ("in fn");
      }

      while (true) {
       window.setTimeout(alertme(), 3000);
   alert("left fn");
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The only reason that the `alert("in fn")` ever shows is that the `alert("left fn")` returns control to the browser inside the loop. If you didn't have the alert in the loop, the loop would just start timeouts and never end, so the timeout events would never be handled. The browser would just freeze up.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks, good point. I was also under the impression that setTimeout stopped execution.

Comment: My understanding of this site based on reading the "about" link is that I should vote for the "best" answer which would be Jonathan. @clph3r Sorry I'd vote for you too if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few probable issues:

1. `alertme()` is being called immediately and its `return` value is instead being passed to `setTimeout()`.

   To fix this, you can pass `alertme` as a reference (without the calling parenthesis):

   ```
   setTimeout(alertme, 3000);
   ```
2. However, this will then conflict with JavaScript's (primarily) single-threaded nature.

   The `setTimeout()`s, being asynchronous, simply start a timer that expires *no less than* 3 seconds from *now.* But, they require that the one thread is eventually **not** busy for the delayed task to be performed.

   However, the `while (true) {}`, being synchronous and indefinite, will keep the thread busy until all execution is stopped and will never allow the timeouts to perform their tasks. So, you will never see `"in fn"`.

   John Resig has a good write up on timers: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

How exactly to *fix* the code depends on the intent.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very helpful response. So... I am new here. With two valid answers, one quicker and the other more thorough, who gets the check mark?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (true) {
    window.setTimeout(alertme, 3000); //setTimeout wants a function, not the return value of the function
    alert("left fn");
}
```

btw, have fun with klicking all the messageboxes away...

Comment: wow, quick response. I'm glad it was something simple. I'm learning javascript by trial and error. Lots of each. Thanks much!